Spiric sections by imaginary planes
To quote a previous question on spiric sections:

The spiric section is the curve obtained by slicing a torus along a plane parallel to its axis.


In comparison, Wikipedia uses an algebraic definition of the curve rather than a geometric one:

A spiric section is a quartic plane curve defined by equations of the form $(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}=dx^{2}+ey^{2}+f$.
$\ldots$
A spiric section is sometimes defined as the curve of intersection of a torus and a plane parallel to its rotational symmetry axis. However, this definition does not include all of the curves given by the previous definition unless imaginary planes are allowed.

In other words, the algebraic definition allows sections by imaginary planes as well as real ones. My question is,
What is the condition on parameters $d,e,f$ such that

the curve restricted to $x$ and $y$ real is non-empty
the curve is not a section of a real torus by a real plane

are both satisfied?

Wikipedia derived expressions for $d,e,f$ in terms of $a,b$ (about the torus) and $c$ (about the plane):
$$\label1\tag1
d=2(a^{2}+b^{2}-c^{2})\\ e=2(a^{2}-b^{2}-c^{2})\\ f=-(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(a-b-c).$$
WA calculates $$\label2\tag2
a=\pm\frac{\sqrt{d^2+4 f}}{2 \sqrt{d-e}} ,\quad b=\pm\frac{\sqrt{d-e}}{2} ,\quad c= \pm\frac{\sqrt{e^2+4 f}}{2\sqrt{d-e}} ,\quad d \neq e$$

I came up with an example, $d=3,e=1,f=-1$. The curve $\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2=3 x^2+y^2-1$

is not a section by real plane,
because \eqref{1} has no real solutions in $a,b,c$.
Plugging in \eqref{2},
$$a=\pm\frac{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}}{2},\quad b=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\quad c=\pm\frac{\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}{2} i $$
So the torus is real but the plane is imaginary.

In Mathematica,
Reduce[!Resolve[Exists[{a,b,c},
d ==2(a^2+b^2-c^2)&& e ==2(a^2-b^2-c^2)&&f==-(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(a-b-c)],{d,e,f}, Reals]&&!Resolve[Exists[{a,b,c},
e ==2(a^2+b^2-c^2)&& d ==2(a^2-b^2-c^2)&&f==-(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(a-b-c)],{d,e,f}, Reals]&&Resolve[Exists[{x,y},(x^2+y^2)^2==d x^2+e y^2+f],{d,e,f}, Reals]]

outputs a disjunction of many Boolean expressions
(e>0&&-(e^2/4)<=f<0&&d==0)||(f>0&&e==0&&d==0)||(e>0&&-(e^2/4)<f<0&&d==0)||(e>0&&f>-(e^2/4)&&d==e)||(e>0&&-e<d<0&&-(e^2/4)<=f<-(d^2/4))||(e>0&&-e<d<0&&-(e^2/4)<=f<-(d^2/4))||(e<=0&&d>-e&&-(d^2/4)<=f<-(e^2/4))||(e>0&&d>e&&-(d^2/4)<=f<-(e^2/4))||(e>0&&0<d<e&&-(e^2/4)<=f<-(d^2/4))||(f>=0&&e<0&&d==e)||(e>0&&-e<d<0&&-(e^2/4)<f<-(d^2/4))||(e>0&&-e<d<0&&-(e^2/4)<f<-(d^2/4))||(e<=0&&d>-e&&-(d^2/4)<=f<-(e^2/4))||(e>0&&d>e&&-(d^2/4)<=f<-(e^2/4))||(e>0&&0<d<e&&-(e^2/4)<f<-(d^2/4))

The example $d=3,e=1,f=-1$ satisfies one of them: $(e>0\land d>e\land -\frac{d^2}{4}\leq f<-\frac{e^2}{4})$
